# Duality between spanning and linearly independent and between surjective and injective

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V$ and $W$ be two vector spaces over a given field $F$ and let $\phi \in \text{Hom}(V,W)$. Assume $(v_i)_{i \in I}$ is an arbitrary (indexed) collection of vectors in $V$

I managed to prove that:

- $(v_i)_i$ lin. ind. $\implies$ $(\phi(v_i))_i$ lin. ind., provided that $\phi$ is injective
- $(\phi(v_i))_i$ lin. ind. $\implies$ $(v_i)_i$ lin. ind.

and also that

- $(v_i)_i$ spanning $\implies$ $(\phi(v_i))_i$ spanning, provided that $\phi$ is surjective.

Assumimg I said nothing false so far (otherwise please do let me know), I was quite confident that I could prove

- $(\phi(v_i))_i$ spanning $\implies$ $(v_i)_i$ spanning.

But this is quite clearly not true in general. It is true, I think, as long as $\phi$ is injective.

Did I say anything wrong? How come this kind of 'duality' breaks down? How can I find some elegant 'dual' results along these lines?

I don't know exactly what I mean by 'dual', I was just looking for some elegance...

Admittedly related to this [Linear independence, Spanning, Injectivity, and Surjectivity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1479983/linear-independence-spanning-injectivity-and-surjectivity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One has 
\begin{equation}
\text{Im}(\phi) = \text{span}(\phi(v_i))_i \Longleftrightarrow
V = \ker(\phi) + \text{span}(v_i)_i \
\end{equation}
Indeed if $x\in V$, one can write $\phi(x) = \sum \lambda_i \phi(v_i)$, hence
$x - \sum \lambda_i v_i \in \ker \phi$. The sum is not $\oplus$ because $\text{span}(v_i)$ could contain vectors in $\ker(\phi)$. In fact one could add arbitrary vectors from $\ker(\phi)$ to the $v_i$ family.

In particular, if $(\phi(v_i))_i$ is spanning $W$, then $\text{Im}(\phi) = \text{span}(\phi(v_i))_i$

Comment: under no assumptions at all on $(v_i)_i$?

Comment: Also: $+$ or $\bigoplus$?

Comment: Nice, thank you.. Accepted!